# Explain the behaviour of 1-bit bit-fields

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct value{
       int bit1 : 1;
       int bit3 : 4;
       int bit4 : 4;
       }bit={1,2,2};
     printf("%d %d %d\n",bit.bit1,bit.bit3,bit.bit4);
     return 0;
}
```

Output :

-1 2 2

Please explain the oupput of the program ?

Comment: It is implementation defined whether `int` bit-fields are `signed int` or `unsigned int`. On some compilers you could get `1 2 2` as output. For portability, you should use either `unsigned int` or `signed int` for bit-fields. Or not use bit-fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably the only curious output is the first one.

Well, consider the range of values that a 1-bit [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos-complement) integer can represent.

Comment: Can you please explain the output in a bit detail ? How is it actually storing the values in its fields ? Say if I change bit1 : 1 bit2 : 8 bit3 : 8 its showing -1 -8 -8 as output,why is so ?

Comment: @code_hacker: You need to read about how two's-complement works (see the link in my answer).  It should make sense then.

Answer (score 9):

`bit1` is a signed 1-bit integer, that can hold the values `-1` and `0` only.

Comment: An the initialization makes a conversion from an (signed) integer `1` into that range, so this is even undefined behavior, no?

Answer (score 2):

Note the below statement inside
the struct:

int bit1:1;  --> 'int' indicates
that it is a SIGNED integer.
For signed integers the leftmost bit will be taken for +/- sign.
If you store 1 in 1-bit field:
The left most bit is 1, so the
system will treat the value as
negative number.

The 2's complement method is
used by the system to handle the
negative values.

Therefore, the data stored is 1. 
The 2's complement of 1 is also 1
(negative).

Therefore -1 is printed.

If you store 2 in 4-bits field:
Binary 2: 0010 (left most bit is 0,
so system will treat it as positive value) 0010 is 2
Therefore 2 is printed.

Comment: For bit-fields, `int` does not necessary mean SIGNED. The gcc manual states: "The ISO C standard leaves it up to the implementation whether a bit-field declared plain int is signed or not. This in effect creates two alternative dialects of C." However, both gcc and MSVC take it as signed: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yszfawxh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Non_002dbugs.html.